# Passing a StreamReader object by Reference

Tags: c#, iostream, streamreader

I'm creating a small file parsing console app using C# in VS 2013.  I'm using `StreamReader` to read in the file and creating objects from data in the file by parsing the lines.

I call a method, `CreateHeader()`, to create a Header object and pass the `StreamReader` object to read those particular lines, create a Header object, and return the object to the calling method.  I'm passing the `StreamReader` object by reference because I'm wanting the `StreamReader` to be updated in the calling method to get the next line in the file where the `CreateHeader()` method left off.  However, when the object is returned to the calling method, the `StreamReader` object wasn't updated and it still is at the same line in the file when the `CreateHeader()` method was called.

How would I pass a `StreamReader` object to another function and have that `StreamReader` be updated in the calling function?  Here is some sample code:

```
static Header CreateHeader(ref StreamReader sr)
{
    Header hd = new Header();

    string formTitle = string.Empty;
    string[] words;
    string _line = string.Empty;;

    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        _line = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(_line);
    }
}

static void ParseLines()
{
    Header _hd = CreateHeader(ref sr);
    _line = sr.ReadLine();
    prodList = new List<InventoryActivityProducts>();
}
```

Comment: Apparently, all objects are passed by ref.  Only value types are passed by value.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `ref`.  http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: How do you know the `StreamReader` is on the same line?  `ref` won't change that.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne "all objects are passed by ref" - no, all parameters are passed _by value_ (unless you specify `ref` or `out`) but for reference types the value _is_ a reference.

Comment: @DStanley - even when the reference is passed by value, the object (instance) is always effectively passed by-ref.

Comment: SLaks, thanks for the link.  That's a great link.  I appreciate you sending that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the way you are using the `StreamReader` in your example (regardless of the `ref`) it should do what you are trying to achieve. Since you are not initializing the stream reader (`sr`) in your example, the error is probably in what you are not showing. In either case, the stream reader keeps a `Position` property internally that dictates where in the stream it should read next. Without modifying this property, the reader will simply continue where it left off.

Second, this behavior is possible because the stream reader is a reference type. Without getting too deep, this means when you pass the instance of a reader to a method, it pass the address of where the method resides in memory (something like `0x0FA7230`); this is in contrast to a value type, where the instance is passed by value (the actual value of the variable, like `4`). Thus, when you call `ReadLine` on the stream reader, it is calling that method on the same instance as the outer method (thus why it should work as you intend). Using `ref` is a slightly different concept altogether (and unfortunate that it stands for *reference*). Passing a variable using `ref` (regardless of it being a reference or value type) will pass the address of the variable (note, *not* the address of the instance), or in effect an address of an address for reference types and an address to a value for value types. This is useful when you want to initialize a variable in an inner method and use the result in the outer method (effectively another way to return multiple values from a method); but other than that you will most probably not need to use it.

Comment: Hello rae1,  you're right.  It was doing what I wanted it to do.  I caught that over the weekend.  Not sure what I was looking at.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are Streams also reference types?